# Why am I getting undefined when I try to fetch ._id?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios, mern

So I'm trying to grab the **._id** of after storing it to **buyerInfo** and then throw it to **handleClick** and console.log it, but when I try to console.log it, I received an undefined value.

> buyerId: undefined

```
   const [buyerInfo, setBuyerInfo] = useState([])
   useEffect(() =>{
      const getBuyer = async () =>{
        const res = await publicRequest.get(`/users/studentId/${buyer_id}`)
        setBuyerInfo(res.data)   
      }
      getBuyer()
    },[product_id, seller_id, buyer_id])

    const [itemName, setItemName] = useState({
      productId: product_id,
      buyerId: buyerInfo._id,
      sellerId: seller_id
  
    })

   const handleClick = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(itemName)
   }
```

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: can you show us what you receive from the request?

Comment: what do you mean by request?

Comment: open your console, press the network tab and preview the data. If we can see what you get we can provide better help

Comment: @OzanMudul, i update it, i dont receive an error, btw, I'm also fetching the other data, and the text on the left side came from **buyerInfo** itself

Comment: `getBuyer` is async. Are you sure, your request already finished, when you try to access `buyerInfo._id`?

Comment: @Stykgwar something like this: https://imgur.com/a/m5phHIV and open the data so we can see what is inside, my guess is you are handling it with incorrect variable name

Answer (score 0):

I asked someone and tried this one by putting it directly to the useEffect, not a good approach but working, I guess? heehe.

```
 useEffect(() =>{
  const getBuyer = async () =>{
    try {
      const res = await publicRequest.get(`/users/studentId/${buyer_id}`)
      setItemName(prev=> ({...prev, buyerId: res.data._id}))
      setBuyerInfo(res.data)   
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  getBuyer()
},[product_id, seller_id, buyer_id])
```